# Reading Text File from Xcode Bundle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, file, bundle

Why can't I read the content of foo.rtf? I've already put it in Xcode bundle. fileRoot still contains null.

```
NSString* filePath = @"foo";
NSString* fileRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath ofType:@"rtf"];       

NSLog(@"File root contains %@", fileRoot);
```

---

@TheAmateurProgrammer, Thank you for the diagram. I just added foo.rtf into the bundle resources. The result for fileRoot is still null. What step am I still missing?

Target's "Copy Bundle Resources" in Build Phases now contains foo.rtf. (I can't insert picture as I'm still a newbie).

(I will add the content reading after I can get fileRoot to point correctly).

Comment: Can you show what your code actually does to create the file path?  Im sure its not foo.

Answer (score 8):

You added the file, but is it really copied to your application bundle?

[image]

Make sure your rtf file is copied into your resource.

Secondly, you're only getting the path of the rtf, and not the contents of the rtf.

```
NSString *fileRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath ofType:@"rtf"]; 
NSString *contents = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithRTF:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileRoot] documentAttributes:NULL] string];
```

That will get the contents of the rtf.

Comment: I'm not only up voting your answer because it helped me, but also because of your awesome nickname

Answer (score 0):

First check that your file is present inside the bundle or not and if it present it must have same name as "foo.rtf".

You are getting nil because your file is not present directly inside in the bundle.

once you get the right file path you can get the content of your text file as a string by calling initWithContentsOfFile method on NSString class.

Comment: Thank you, kidsid49, that's what I was missing. I have now done that step, but still have nil pointer.

Comment: Make sure that you have added that text file to your current target.  You can confirm this by clicking on that text file and then check that it is added to your current target.The checkbox in left side inspector must be checked for current target.

Comment: Yes, target membership under inspector is already ticked (on the left of the project name). Pointer of fileRoot is still nil. :(

Comment: What about your file name is that have same name "foo.rtf" ?