# Mac OSX: how to get content of a text file located somewhere on disk?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, file, filesystems

I found some posts explaining how to get the content of a text file included in the project bundle. For example here: [Reading Text File from XCode Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995661/reading-text-file-from-xcode-bundle)

My question is: once I have the NSString describing the path to my txt file (for example pathString = @"/Users/username/Documents/theFile.txt"), how can I get its content in a string ?

Thanks !

Comment: Note that having an absolute path of that form statically compiled into your app is guaranteed to fail.   You really should be using the various APIs on the system to derive paths to appropriate locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want this:

```
NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fullpath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Note that there are quite a few related questions on StackOverflow with usage examples etc - just search for "stringWithContentsOfFile".